# Using ListView to read binary file

Tags: c#, .net, file, listview, binary

I have made this exe that contains a listview, so when I open a binary file, it shows text pointers in a column and text strings in another column.

I managed to show the pointers, using the "for loop", but I had no idea on how to use the loop to show text strings, so what I want to use, is to loop through the pointers, to show the text it points to, and stop at 00 00 after each text.

and [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?mr79ecpomq77w8z) is a sample on the binary file structure.

The first 4 bytes of the binary files are the pointers/strings amount, the next 4 bytes * the 1st 4 bytes are the pointers, the rest is texts strings, each string is separated by 00 00 and are all Unicode.

So can anyone please help me on how to show strings for each pointer in the Strings Column?

EDIT: here is teh code for the button that opens the binary file:

```
        private void menuItem8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Open File";
        ofd.Filter = "Data Files (*.dat)|*.dat|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File opened Succesfully!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            path = ofd.FileName;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path));               
            int num_pointers = br.ReadInt32();
            textBox1.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < num_pointers; i++)
            {
                br.BaseStream.Position = i * 4 + 4;
                listView1.Items.Add(br.ReadUInt32().ToString("X"));
            }
            br.Close();
            br = null;
        }
        ofd.Dispose();
        ofd = null;
    }
```

Comment: Take the time and trouble to post (the relevant parts of) your code here.

Comment: added code, if you need anything else, please comment.

Comment: are you finding it difficult to convert byte array to string?

Comment: yeah, especially when there are a lot of strings, i just need a way to loop through the pointer column, and show the string taht each pointer points to in the 2nd column.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, supply the encoding when instantiating the BinaryReader like so:

```
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path), Encoding.Unicode);
```

Next, you want to keep a list of the read offsets. (You can still add them to the ListView later on):

```
List<int> offsets = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < num_pointers; i++)
{
    // Note: There is no need to set the position in the stream as
    // the Read method will advance the stream to the next position
    // automatically.
    // br.BaseStream.Position = i * 4 + 4;
    offsets.Add(br.ReadInt32());
}
```

Finally, you go through the list of offsets and read the strings from the file. You may want to put them into some data structure so that later on you can populate the View with the data:

```
Dictionary<int,string> values = new Dictionary<int,string>();
for (int i = 0; i < offsets.Count; i++)
{
    int currentOffset = offsets[i];

    // If it is the last offset we just read until the end of the stream
    int nextOffset = (i + 1) < offsets.Count ? offsets[i + 1] : (int)br.BaseStream.Length;

    // Note: Under the supplied encoding, a character will take 2 bytes.
    // Therefore we will need to divide the delta (in bytes) by 2.
    int stringLength = (nextOffset - currentOffset - 1) / 2;

    br.BaseStream.Position = currentOffset;

    var chars = br.ReadChars(stringLength);
    values.Add(currentOffset, new String(chars));
}

// Now populate the view with the data...
foreach(int offset in offsets)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(offset.ToString("X")).SubItems.Add(values[offset]);
}
```

Comment: **fs** is not declared, and `offsets.Add(br.ReadInt32());
` doesn't add anything to the Pointers column in the listview, so i removed the `br.BaseStream.Position = i * 4 + 4;` and it worked as you said thank you, but still didn't get the second code quite well :s

Comment: You may replace `fs` with `br.BaseStream.Length`. (I updated the answer accordingly.)

Comment: still not working :s i added them to the button click event, shouldn't i ?
it doesn't show the strings, Thank you for your time :)